# Can closedXML write out an HTML table for Excel

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel, closedxml

I have an HTML table that is dynamic and has tags:

```
table, th, thead, td, tbody, tr and a div at the end
```

It also has colspans too.

Can closedXML just import this into a worksheet as is and render it out as XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ClosedXML can not import HTML.

You have to parse the HTML yourself (using something like [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)) and put the content of each cell in the HTML table in the corresponding cell of the ClosedXML spreadsheet.