# C# - How to used for StringBuilder in Export Datatable to excel using ClosedXml

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I am Using the this code below in

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        System.Data.DataTable dt;
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=sanjay;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from login",con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         dt=new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        int srno = 1;

        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();

        ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
        String Todaysdate1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        string appPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\");
        if (!Directory.Exists(appPath + "\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\TD"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "\\" + Todaysdate1);
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           stb.Append("<html>");
             stb.Append("<head>");
             stb.Append("</head>");
             stb.Append("<body>");
             stb.Append("Sanju");
             stb.Append("<table border=2>");
             stb.Append("<tbody>");
             stb.Append("<tr style='height:25px'>");
             stb.Append("<td  colspan='18' style='text-align:center;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;min-width:50px'>");
             stb.Append("<center> Form III - DEAF Voucher Preparation</center>");
             stb.Append("</td>");
             stb.Append("</tr>");
             stb.Append("<tr style='height:21px'>");
             stb.Append("<td colspan='18' style='text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;min-width:50px'>");
             stb.Append("<center>2018-05-01</center>");
             stb.Append("</td>");
             stb.Append("</tr>");
             stb.Append("<tr style='height:100px;font-weight:bold'>");
             stb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px'>No.</td>");
             stb.Append("</tr>");

             for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 stb.Append("<tr>");
                 stb.Append("<td>" + srno++ + " </td>");
                 stb.Append("<td nowrap>" + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "</td>");
                 stb.Append("<td style='background-color:#ff99cc'></td>");
                 stb.Append("<td style='background-color:#ff99cc'></td>");
                 stb.Append("<td style='background-color:#ff99cc'></td>");
                 stb.Append("</tr>");
                 wb.Worksheets.Add(srno.ToString(), i);//Add worksheet
             }
             stb.Append("</tbody>");
             stb.Append("</table>");
             stb.Append("</body>");
             stb.Append("</html>");

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(appPath + "\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\TD_Results_From.XLS"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(stb.ToString());   
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath + "\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\TD_Results_From.XLS");
        }
```

I am used the `Wb.SavaAs()` only show the add worksheet but first worksheet not open I will access workbook and all worksheet each recede create the worksheet.
Add Multiple worksheet I am Using `wb.Worksheets.Add(srno.ToString(), i);` this statement 
I am also using the `closedXml`

The problem is a only create the main worksheet but never open the all worksheet

Any Body Help Me 
Advance Thank You

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML can not import HTML.

[Can closedXML write out an HTML table for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272326/1442180)

> You have to parse the HTML yourself (using something like [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)) and put the content of each cell in the HTML table in the corresponding cell of the ClosedXML spreadsheet

You should do it like this:

```
public void WriteDataToExcel(DataTable dt, string fileName)  
{  
  using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())  
  {  
      //Add DataTable in worksheet  
      wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);  
      using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))  
      {  
          wb.SaveAs(stream);  
      }  
  }  
}
```

Also, you could use `Open XML` like this sample project to export XLS:

[Creating basic Excel workbook with Open XML](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML)